# Subsonic 3 SVN Checkout and T4

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, t4

Hey guys, I am a little confused as to how to get the T4 templates and use them when you pull down the latest code from SVN for Subsonic 3.  Are there any instructions anywhere for this or could someone enlighten me?  I looked @ the old alpha release and there was a nice _Generated folder that held all of these files.  I'm curious what I need to do to create that folder???

Thanks for your help,
Larry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

they're in the SubSonic.Templates project. Choose your poison (there's two right now - ActiveRecord and Advanced) and drop them in whichever folder works for you.

Comment: Yes, and save them to re-compile them.